# How to systematically (ie: algorithmically) generate permutations of a set?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given the first $n$ natural numbers, how do you systematically generate all of the $n!$ permutations of that set?  I can do it for a known $n$ using a computer program, but it requires $n$ nested loops.  I'm sure there must be a more efficient way.

Comment: You probably want to use recursion, a function that calls itself. Instead of $n$ loops you have a function with one loop that calls itself $n$ levels deep. So effectively you do the same, but now $n$ can be variable.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to stay away from recursion? (Because it's not practically scalable for large $n$?)

Comment: I suppose recursion could work.  Presumably any recursive algorithm can be modified to be a stack-based algorithm, so it's all good.  I guess the questions are: a) is recursion (or some method based on it) the only way and b) if not, how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_n$ is the set of all permutations of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ then a recursive formulation is

$$ S_{n+1} = \bigcup_{i=0}^n\ \{ f_i(s) \mid s \in S_n \}$$

where $f_i(s)$ denotes the permutation obtained by inserting $n+1$ after the $i$-th entry of the $n$-permutation $s$.
(For $i=0$ this is inserting in the first place.)

You can write this as a tail-recursive algorithm if you define a helper function, but maybe the details of that are a better fit on e.g. StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write a program in Python then there is itertools.combinations that will create all combinations of an arbitrary size of a given set.

Comment: My interest is in how that algorithm works, not in generating the permutations themselves.  I can do it in MATLAB, too, but I don't know how *MATLAB* does it.